# Java - Extending Unknown Classes

Tags: java, class, extend

I wanted to create a class that can extend an unknown class that is provided at runtime. I thought that I could do something like this:

```
public class Foo<T extends Bar> extends T {}
```

but that doesn't work. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Extending classes have to be known at compile-time to enable the compiler to check overridings and implementations of abstract methods at compile-time.

Comment: How can you extend it if you don't know what it is?

Answer (score 1):

Not without some crazy runtime code generation. Java's generics are not the same sort of thing as C++'s templates: Internally, `T` is simply treated as an `Object`, and up- and down-casted as necessary for the benefit of your code. So while a C++ template is instantiated for a particular `T`, and can decide at compile-time whether that works, in Java the machinery underlying inheritance requires that the actual base class be decided upon in the class definition itself.